# jquery validation for enumdropdownlistfor

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-validate

I have this code

Razor page:

```
            <div class="editor-label">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Citizenship)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
              @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Citizenship)
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Citizenship)
            </div>
```

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Гражданство")]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
public CitizenshipEnum? Citizenship { get; set; }
```

And finally I got this HTML:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="Пожалуйста, укажите значение" id="Citizenship" name="Citizenship"><option value=""></option>
<option value="RF">Российская Федерация</option>
<option value="other">другое государство</option>
</select>
```

what is wrong with validation for this?
unobtrusive.js and other required scripts definitely loaded (with other inputs validation works normally)

I'm trying to solve this problem with adding custom rule

like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(function () {
  $.validator.addMethod('selectNone', function (value, element) { debugger; return $(element).val(); }, "Please select an option");

  $("form").validate({
    rules: {
      '#Citizenship': {
        selectNone: true
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue right now. 
The enum gets 0 value if no item selected from the dropdownlist, maybe for the jquery validator it is a proper value, so it passes the validation.

Therefore I added a range validation attribute for my enum type:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
[EnumDataType(typeof(Priority))]
public Priority Priority { get; set; }
```

After that, the jquery validation worked as I wanted.

Note: By adding the [EnumDataType] attribute, the ModelState will be invalid in the controller if no item has been selected, so you can use it for validation in the controller.

Comment: Another alternative is to make the field nullable in your viewmodel, and mark it as required.

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit ( ClassOfModel model )
    {
        if ( ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            if ( model.Citizenship == null )
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError( "Citizenship", "Пожалуйста, укажите значение" );
            }
            // Do something (e.g. save data)
        }
        return View( model );
    }
```